# How to stop LIMIT from slowing down query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-limit

I created a test table with 100k rows in it. The execution time for this query:

```
SELECT id FROM table
```

Is `0.032s`. If I add a `GROUP BY` statement for an integer column that is indexed as `Normal,BTREE`, the execution time for the query:

```
SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY indexedColumn
```

EXPLAIN output:

```
id | select_type | table | type |    possible keys   | key  | key_len | ref |  rows  | Extra
 1      SIMPLE    [table]  All    [indexedColumnKey]   null    null    null   105416   Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Is `0.073s`. The execution time doubled due to the `GROUP BY`, but I'm assuming that's normal? The question I have, is why does adding `LIMIT` to the query, like this:

```
SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY indexedColumn LIMIT 500
```

EXPLAIN output:

```
id | select_type | table | type |      possible keys    |        key        | key_len | ref |  rows  | Extra
 1      SIMPLE    [table]  index    [indexedColumnKey]   [indexedColumnKey]      5      null   500     null
```

Increases the execution time to `0.301s`? That's a slowdown of over 4x.

I'm very inexperienced with SQL, so maybe this is totally normal, but it just seems counter-intuitive to me that limiting the number of rows returned slows the query down so much.

Questions:

1. Is this normal?
2. Is there any way to stop LIMIT from slowing down the query so much?

Comment: how did you measure this?

Comment: If you prefix the query with Explain you'll get the plan, suspicion is it's doing a secondary sort to discover the "first" 500.

Comment: @Nanne You mean the execution times? I got them out of Navicat after executing the queries.

Comment: but did you do it once? because then it could just be query cache, some other process that slowed something down, etc etc....

Comment: @Nanne I ran both queries a bunch of times and the execution times were always pretty much the same.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I'll update my question now, posting the output of `EXPLAIN`

Comment: The 2nd (and 3rd) query (`SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY indexedColumn`) are meaningless and will produce an error if the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` setting is enabled. Think about it for a moment, for any value of the `indexedColumn`, there are many values of `id`. Which one should be returned? (and if you are wondering, yeah, MySQL does return an arbitrary one when that setting is not enabled.)

Comment: In short, don't use `GROUP BY` this way.

Comment: Not related to your question, but using limit without an order by clause is potentially pointless.  You are saying that you only want 500 records, but are not specifying which 500.

Comment: @ypercube What can I use to group rows together if not `GROUP BY`? The fact that `GROUP BY` returns an arbitrary row out of the rows group actually is a problem for me, but I don't know of any alternative..

Comment: `SELECT MIN(id) AS firstId FROM table GROUP BY indexedColumn;` is an example (You can use MAX instead of MIN, or both.)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I just added the output of `EXPLAIN` for both of the queries.

Answer (score 0):

The query `SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY indexedColumn` does not use index. It is shown in your explain. But when you use limit the index is used.
Also, for experiments you could disable cache using SQL_NO_CACHE `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ....`

Comment: Shouldn't an index make it faster, not slower?

Comment: @Nate,index should make it faster. Could you please `set profiling=1;` run first query with SQL_NO_CACHE, then the second, after `show profiles;` and post the results;